# How to remove all type of prefix salutation from string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

Suppose I have string coming from Input with name (for eg: `Mr . Aditya Jha`). How do I remove salutation from the start of input?

List of salutations that can come are:

```
Mr, Mrs, Dr, Miss, Ms, Rev, Mr. , Mr. , Dr. , Miss. , Ms. , Rev. , Mr . , Mr . , Dr . , Miss . , Ms . , Rev .
```

Any solution or regex statement which can consider all of these salutations?

I tried this:

```
name.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").replaceFirst("(?i)(Mr . )", "").replaceFirst("(?i)(Mr |Mr. )", "").trim()
```

It is working, but for name like `amra khan`, it is removing `mr`.

Comment: I have to use replace two times--First to remove the third possibility, then to remove the first two. Is there any better approach ?

Comment: Yes there are a solution, just use `Mr\s*\.?\\s* ` some people here close and down-vote question and answer for that I removed my correct answer

Comment: Does it mean you only need to replace it at the start of the string? Try `.replaceFirst("(?i)^\\s*Mr\\b[\\s.]*", "")`. If anywhere inside the string, use ``.replaceFirst("(?i)\\bMr\\b[\\s.]*", "")``.

Comment: If you need an answer, please explain what you need.

Comment: I tried this : name.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").replaceFirst("(?i)(Mr . )", "").replaceFirst("(?i)(Mr |Mr. )", "").trim(); It is working, but for name like amra khan, it is removing mr

Comment: Also, this is only one salutation. I have a exhaustive list of 20 saluations (like Mrs. , Dr. , Rev. etc) that has also to be removed if they come with the name.

Comment: So, please add all the relevant details to the question. Also, when you provide feedback, add `@` and user name for the user to get notified of this feedback.

Comment: So, this is still not clear if these salutations come at the start of string, or anywhere in the string. Try `"(?i)\\b(M(?:iss|rs?|s)|Dr|Rev)\\b[\\s.]*"` with `replaceAll`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AWkbvZ/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated the question with relevant details

Comment: But please revert your attempt. Please see the comments, please provide feedback. I believe [my last suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078462/how-to-remove-all-type-of-prefix-salutation-from-string-in-java?noredirect=1#comment108168907_61078462) covers all your cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It worked for me.  I tried this:  replaceFirst("(?i)^(Rev|Prof|Ms|Miss|Smt|Sri|Shri|Shree|Mrs|Mr|Dr|Jr|Sr)(\\s\\.|\\.|)\\s", "" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").replaceFirst("(?i)^\\s*(?:M(?:iss|rs?|s)|Dr|Rev)\\b[\\s.]*", "").trim();
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AWkbvZ/2)

**Pattern details**

- `(?i)` - case ignoring option
- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:M(?:iss|rs?|s)|Dr|Rev)` - `M` followed with `iss`, `r`, `rs`, `s`, or `Dr` or `Rev` (you may add more after `|` here)
- `\b` - word boundary
- `[\s.]*` - 0 or more whitespaces or dots.